# using .not() with .click() to ignore class

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a checkbox in each row. I want to do a .click function that happens when I click anywhere on the tr other than the checkbox.

The rows have class="message" and the td that contains the checkbox has class="ignore_checkbox".

this is my jquery/js:

```
$('.message').not('.ignore_checkbox').click(respondToMessage);
```

but it still calls respondToMessage function when I click the checkbox. Any ideas?

```
<?php foreach ($accountMessages as $accountMessage): ?>
<tr class="message overview">
    <td class="ignore_checkbox" ><?php echo $this->Form->checkbox(
        'AccountMessages.'.$accountMessage['AccountMessage']['id'], 
        array('value' => $accountMessage['AccountMessage']['id'],
        'hiddenField' => false,
        'multiple' => true)); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong><?php echo h($accountMessage['Account']['email']);?></strong><br/>
        <span class="message_time"><?php echo $this->Time-                      TimeAgoInWords($accountMessage['AccountMessage']['created'], array('format' => 'F jS, Y', 'end' => '+1 year') )?></span>
        <?php echo h($accountMessage['AccountMessage']['title']); ?><br/>
        <?php echo h($accountMessage['AccountMessage']['message']); ?>

    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well (related part of it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the `td` to your existing rule like:

```
$('.message td').not('.ignore_checkbox').click(respondToMessage);
```

Your idea of using `.not()` works but it only works on matching elements. Since your rule starts at the table row `<tr>`, the `.not()` doesn't match anything. By instead matching on the table cells `<td>` it works fine.

Here's a quick **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MrT48/)**.

Comment: This way you cannot click the TD containing the checkbox.

Comment: @JoseFaeti - why do you need to?

Comment: I think that it is best not to be able to click the td containing the checkbox in case someone misses the checkbox by accident. Thank you. This works great!

Comment: Because the OP said "I want to do a .click function that happens when I click anywhere on the tr other than the checkbox." and because maybe the TD contains other things than the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `e.stopPropagation` on the td containing checkbox as on clicking the td will bubble the event up to `TR`

```
$('.ignore_checkbox').click (function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or you can handle it inside `.message` handler like in other answers.

Comment: This is bad, as you attach more event listeners (possibly doubling them) than needed. You already have event listeners on the rows containing the checkboxes, no need to add additional ones. In fact, only a single event listener in the <table> element would be event better.

Comment: @JoseFaeti _In fact, only a single event listener in the <table> element would be event better._ --- It totally depends on what he has inside his handler.. I can go ahead and use `e.target` but still that wouldn't handle any better.

Comment: But you will save resources, and that's (usually) preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$('.message').on('click', function(e) {

```
if( e.target.className.indexOf('ignore_checkbox') > -1 
     || e.target.type == 'checkbox'){
       // do Nothing
 }
else{
     alert('Not checkbox');
}
```

});​

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7QwHm/)**

Comment: Think this always will go fail cause the Note has the className `message` already.. Use `this.className.indexOf("...") !== -1`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.message').click(function(event) {

    if ( ! $(event.target).hasClass('ignore_checkbox') )
    {
        respondToMessage();
    }
});
```

As always I would suggest to use only one event listener to the  element, which will be able to listen to the click event on every row it contains. This way you save resources and need only one single event listener for everything.

[Check the fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/u7Juu/)

Answer (score 0):

Try use event bubbling.

```
$('.message').on('click', ':not(.ignore_checkbox)', function(event) {
// enter code here
});
```